# What's the difference between "text/event-stream" and "application/stream+json"

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

```
@GetMapping(path = "/cars", produces = "text/event-stream")
public Flux<Car> getCarStream() {
    System.out.println("application/stream+json");
    return this.repository.findCarsBy().log();
}
```

What's the difference between the above code and the following:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/cars", produces = "application/stream+json")
public Flux<Car> getCarStream() {
    System.out.println("application/stream+json");
    return this.repository.findCarsBy().log();
}
```

So far I've found the contradictory information: some say they both mean server-sent events and others that there is a difference.

Comment: It would help if you linked to the information you mentioned.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-server-sent-events-tutorial MediaType.APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE signifies that the server will send SSEs
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Orluu4VhmY 31:46 APPLICATION_STREAM_JSON_VALUE is used if you are not in a browser or  streaming up to the server

Answer (score 41):

TL;DR: that dzone article is wrong, and Rossen's talk is right.

`text/event-stream` is the official media type for Server Sent Events (SSE); it will prefix data bits with a `data:` prefix and you can also choose your prefix to change the meaning of that piece of data for the client. This media type is for browsers, as they support that using the `EventSource` JavaScript API.

`application/stream+json` is for server to server/http client (anything that's not a browser) communications. It won't prefix the data and will just use CRLF to split the pieces of data. Note that the Spring team is reconsidering that media type, because [SPR-16742](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-16742) (don't hesitate to comment there!).

Update: `application/x-ndjson` is now the preferred media type for streaming JSON values.

Comment: maybe worth updating as `application/x-ndjson` is now available in latest versions of Spring