# I want to link with the api

Tags: javascript, html, api

I want to link with the api but this link
(https://api.fm-track.com/object-coordinates-stream.json?version=2&api_key=1g6F9NvaKY4jsnmrLqmzxILIMhTpncwr) every time I try to link it with my site

I can't why

this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          url: "https://api.fm-track.com/object-coordinates-stream.json?version=2&api_key=1g6F9NvaKY4jsnmrLqmzxILIMhTpncwr",
          type: "GET",
          success: function(result) {
            console.log(result);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: First of all you should describe your question well. What error are you getting? Are you putting the api keys and the body that the api needs? Have you read the usage? Is the url correct. Check for these and correct your question.

Comment: I want this link Is there a way I can link to this link

Comment: No, the link works and enter it if you want to make sure, but the problem is that it does not work in the api link why?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to modify the link. Is there a way that I can link this link in js language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API actually return `text/event-stream` which is is the official media type for Server Sent Events (SSE)

You can accept SSE like this:

```js
      const evtSource = new EventSource("https://api.fm-track.com/object-coordinates-stream.json?version=2&api_key=1g6F9NvaKY4jsnmrLqmzxILIMhTpncwr");
evtSource.onmessage = function(event) {
  const newElement = document.createElement("li");
  const eventList = document.getElementById("list");
    const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    console.log(data);
  newElement.textContent = "message: " + data['object_id'];
  eventList.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />


    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="list"></ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

For more details:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Server-sent_events/Using_server-sent_events

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_serversentevents.asp

https://stackoverflow.com/a/52099962/11250643

Comment: I want this link Is there a way I can link to this link

Comment: Check my post again @SAQRAL